# Automatically convert scala import sentences into library dependencies

Tags: regex, scala, sbt, dependency-management

I'm new to **Scala** :)

If I understand correctly, you have to first include the needed libraries in the **Library Dependencies** of the `build.sbt` file before you can **import** the needed libraries into the scala script.

However, I have to do it in the other way around. I have to write a **Python** script to transform *automatically* **Scala**'s import sentences into library dependencies sentences, in order to insert them into the `build.sbt` file.

*For example*

From:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import json._
```

to:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.mediamath" %%% "scala-json" % "1.0"
```

I know that the syntex of the library dependencies are as follows:

`libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision % configuration`

And that we should lookup the `groupID`, `artifactID` and `revision` in the [maven central repository](https://search.maven.org/).

However, this manuel lookup doesn't allow me to program the conversion automatically. Is there something that I missed? Other syntex that I can use to accomplish this task? Any other ways?

Comment: In general it is impossible, at best you can have heuristics. You can have several libraries that provide definitions under the same namespace. Even if they aren't you can have a common prefix for all libraries from the same organization/project. Package names doesn't have to align with organization / package name (e.g.there is a lot of `cats` libraries, that share `cats` namespace, but on Maven they are in `org.typelevel` organization). For quite a lot of cases it could work, but this cannot be fully automated.

Comment: If these Scala scripts work, they should have been built or run somehow - I would search for dependencies names there.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thank you a lot for your comments!! By "search for dependencies names", do you mean, e.g.,  <br/>

if there's ```sql``` in the import sentence, I put automatically ```"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion```.  

if there's ```json``` in the import sentence, I put automatically ```"com.mediamath" %%% "scala-json" % "1.0"``` ?  
Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: I mean that the scala script doesn't exist in a vacuum. If this is ammonite, it will have `import $ivy.`organization::library:version`, notebooks often also have similar features. Scastie has a list of libraries used to run script. So usually the dependencies are already defined somewhere.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to build a tool that with a total automation would "guess" the library based on imports because for that one would have to scrap all libraries in existence, check each JAR's content, build index of package -> library name mapping, and then solve the issue of several libraries with the same packages, because there is not rule forbidding that. Due to amount of work no existing tool even tried to automate that. At best you can maintain list of mappings and extends it manually as new case would arrive. It should be simpler to just ask the author what they used.

Comment: Thank you very much @MateuszKubuszok!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in some languages, imports must be done a certain way.  That way looks like "import all the stuff, then start doing things"

In Scala, it is possible to import items at any location within the source code.  This will complicate things.  For example, in Spark code, you indirectly ask the Spark application master for what symbols it offers, which is stored in a variable passed back to you at runtime, and you import those.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

// For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
import spark.implicits._
```

(Note the last line in the example imports anything held in the `implicits` field of a created spark variable.

Finally, there is more than one version of a Maven artifact.  One cannot safely reference any version of a specific Maven artifact, as not all projects attempt to provide backwards compatibility between all version numbers (and even if they attempt to do so, bugs in compatibility can still exist).

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core lists about 30 different versions of spark-core, the core routines used by other spark libraries.  If you pick a version that differs from your existing spark services, your application will not function correctly, as spark is not generally compatible by major version number, but by major and minor version number (2.3 compiled code will fail to work with a 2.4 environment)

In addition, Scala code uses heavy optimizing routines in its compilation phase.  These optimizing routines mean that one cannot generally use a Scala 2.11 class in a Scala 2.12 runtime environment.  All classes must exactly match their runtime environment.  To discover the runtime environment, one doesn't check the import statements, but instead checks the settings of the Scala runtime in the machine where compilation happens, and makes sure they are identical tot the target environments where the output will run.  This is why, for many libraries, you'll see the same version number built multiple times, like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

versus

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

(Example above is fabricated, but illustrates the same version of a library compiled for 2.11 and 2.12)

Finally, the imports are not references to the Maven artifact names.  Rather they are elements within in the JAR files (which are one kind of Maven artifact).  So, you will have an additional problem of discovering which JAR file contains the imported items, without the luxury of knowing which JAR file(s) you are using beforehand.

In short, you are trying to reverse the natural process of how programs are written in this environment with a routine, because you're trying to fix a programmer who didn't document what they intended to use.  However, your routine would have to

1. Take the imports, some of which are possibly built at runtime, and make a list.
2. Take that list of items, and somehow find all the JAR files that could provide the items.
3. For each imported item that is offered by different artifacts, determine (without input) which one of the artifacts was the one the developer intended to use.
4. For the project, discover the desired version of Scala (as determined by the deployment environment(s)), and lookup that artifact's Scala-matching versions.
5. For the list of versions for that artifact, find the version that will work with the rest of the spark infrastructure.

Steps 3 and 5 require solving solutions similar to "I parked my car, here's the keys, go find it" where the car could be anywhere in the world and you can't get more information from the person than "I parked my car"

Step 4 requires discovering something that can't be determined because you probably don't know all the deployment locations, but you can just compile against every version of Scala.

The main point of this post is that you're on a fool's errand.  The sbt file is documentation of what is desired / needed by the developers.  A developer that can't be bothered to write a single line of configuration on what they are using is a nightmare.  A developer that forgot to write that single line is an annoyance that can easily be fixed by asking the developer to do what they forgot to do.

And that's ignoring the Maven core concepts on which SBT was built.  Because assuming you actually managed to successfully navigate steps 1 through 5, not all combinations of library versions work together, as Maven and SBT both to automatic dependency resolution.  This means that if you import org:item:1.1 and org:item2:1.0, org:item2:1.0 might require org:item:1.3 and you'll have a version number conflict in your fully resolved Maven dependencies.  Under conditions like those, only one of the libraries gets used in Java 1.8 projects, and if the used library has incompatibilities with some of the code, people (called build masters) typically need to investigate the build configuration and determine which versions of which artifacts need to be updated to fix the incompatibilities.

If your project could be written, it would be awesome.  Good luck!